# Rails 5 - How to send notifications on real-time manner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, notifications, real-time, actioncable

In rails 5, I am trying to send notifications on real-time manner. I have referred http://jameshuynh.com/rails/react%20js/chat/2017/07/30/build-chat-using-react-js-and-rails-action-cable/

But I have already some methods which will do the same. As per this method, notification should send based on `user_id` dynamically. Even channel is depends on user_id.

In react, header.jsx file,

```
import ActionCable from 'actioncable';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('ws://localhost:3000/cable');

componentDidMount() {
  HttpService.get('/api/v1/notifications', this.getNotificationsSuccess);
  let that = this;
  this.cable.subscriptions.create("NotificationsChannel", {
    user_id: this.state.currentUser.id,
    connected: function () {
     // Timeout here is needed to make sure Subscription
     // is setup properly, before we do any actions.
     setTimeout(() => this.perform('follow', { user_id: this.user_id }),
      1000);
   },
   received: (response) => that.addNotification(response)
 });
}

addNotification = (response) => {
  if(this.refs.notifications){
    this.refs.notifications.addNotification(response.data.notification);
  }
}
```

In rails, connection.rb,

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.full_name
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
      verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed['user.id'])
      if verified_user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
     end
  end
end
```

In notification_channel.rb,

```
class NotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def follow(data)
    stop_all_streams
    stream_from "notifications:#{data['user_id'].to_i}"
  end

  def unfollow
    stop_all_streams
  end
end
```

In notification_broadcast_job.rb,

```
class NotificationsBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(notification, user_id)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "notifications:#{user_id}",
                             data: NotificationSerializer.new(notification)
  end
end
```

In model,

```
after_commit :broadcast_notification

private

def broadcast_notification
  users.each do |user|
    NotificationsBroadcastJob.perform_later(self, user.id)
  end
end
```

With this existing method how can I check real-time notification is working or not?
Right now there is no error and it is not working too. Please help me to implement this feature.